# React exact path in Route doesnt work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Hi I have react app with login page and main page with routes in it. I have trouble understanding  how path and exact path actually works with react router in this kind of situation ?

Here is my code of `App` component:

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component , ...rest }) => {
    const { userAuth, getUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => !userAuth ? <Redirect to='/login' /> : <Component {...props} />}
        />
    )
}

function App(props) {
    return ( 
        <AuthState> 
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/login' component={SignIn} /> 
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={MainPage} /> !!! // When i switch this to path only it works fine
            </Switch> 
        </AuthState>
    );
}

export default App;
```

And here is part of code of `main` component:

```
<main className={classes.content}>
    <div className={classes.toolbar} />
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/dataSets' component={DataSet} />
        <Route path='/dasboard' component={Dashboardmain} />
        <Redirect from='/' to='/dasboard' /> 
    </Switch>
</main>
</div>
```

So when I set like this:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={MainPage} />
```

Routes `/dasboard` and `dataSets` are not rendered, just changed URL-s

But if I set like this:

```
<PrivateRoute path='/' component={MainPage} />
```

Everything works fine.

Any help understanding this kind of behavior?

Comment: Hey did I solve your problem ?? If yes kindly accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exact` is a very helpful prop if you understand it. Basic you can understand it like this:

> Let's use `exact` when you want user to go to **exactly** route (url) you want. If that route is a parent route and it has multiple child routes, don't use `exact` with the parent route, use it for children routes instead

In your example we can understand like this

1. Remember we always have a route parent `/`
2. `Login` is children of `/`, it doesn't contains any child route => so lets add `exact` for this route
3. `MainPage` is a children of `/` too, but it is a parent of `Dashboardmain` and `DataSet` so DONT add `exact` for `/`
4. `Dashboardmain` and `DataSet` are childrens of `/` but they aren't contain any child route => so lets add `exact` for them

The same logic with nested routes. You can create multiple nested routes with my explaination above. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this in your
**App.js**

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/login" component={MyLoginForm} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/onlyAuthorizedAllowedHere/" component={MyComponent} />
</Router>
```

And the PrivateRoute Component

```
import React from 'react'
import AuthService from './Services/AuthService'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  // Add your own authentication on the below line.
  const isLoggedIn = AuthService.isLoggedIn()

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isLoggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```